# PHP Lambda function

Tags: php, lambda, anonymous-function

Hey guys I messed up my Lambda somehow and it seems like my 
anonymous function isn't getting the variables from above,

Some of the vars going in are

```
print_r($cacheTypes); 
print_r($servers); 

Array
(
    [concreter] => on
    [config] => on
)
Array
(
    [0] => dev-www.domain.com
)
```

the function is

```
$urls = array_walk($servers, 
    create_function('&$n', 
        '$n = "http://{$server}/".($vcpParam 
            ? "flush-file-cache" 
            : "flushFileCache.php"
        )."?tags=".implode("-", array_keys($cacheTypes));'
    )
);
```

errors are

```
Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given
Warning: implode() [<a href='function.implode'>function.implode</a>]: Invalid arguments passed
```

Help greatly appreciated. I'm positive it is not recognizing the variables I'm inputing, but I'm not sure why

Comment: What PHP version are you running?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with lambda functions, but in a regular PHP function you would need to declare the variables as globals in the function: `global $cacheTypes;`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
$urls = array_map(function ($var) use($cacheTypes, $vcpParam) {
    return "http://{$var}/" . ($vcpParam ? "flush-file-cache" : "flushFileCache.php") . "?tags=" . implode("-", array_keys($cacheTypes));
}, $servers);
```